# Using jQuery in CRM Dynamics 365 webresource in popup-window

Tags: jquery, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

In my CRM Dynamics 365 solution I have a form with an embedded webresource A. This webresource A opens another webresource B in a popup-window using `window.open`. The opening could of course also be done using  `Xrm.Utility.openWebResource`.

I would like to utilize jQuery in webresource B. I am aware that CRM itself loads jQuery in some version, which is easy to spot when monitoring network requests and filtering for jquery.

The problem is that the webresource B doesn't have "access" to the jQuery or $-variable. The question is what you would recommend to do in order to use jQuery. I've prioritized a list of some possible solutions:

1. Load a webresource with an independent version of jQuery
2. An option I haven't thought of
3. Load it from a CDN
4. Look for all loaded scripts with jQuery and pass the URL to webresource B so it can load it by itself (almost a hack)
5. Avoid jQuery, use vanilla JS

---

UPDATE:
The main reason for using jQuery was to easily resize an iframe (with random contents) embedded in popup-window which displayed webresource B according to the dimensions of the popup-window.

I decided to lose jQuery altogether and use CSS instead. My solution became this which work nicely in Google Chrome, Windows Edge and Internet Explorer 11:

```
#externalframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: What are you using jQuery for? My personal preference is option #5

Comment: Brain thinks: Width and height dynamic, update iframe when window resize, jQuery make job easy. Heart says: There's got to be a better (and cleaner) way. So I came up with perhaps the most easy solution: CSS. See my update on my question.

Comment: This is why SO is particular on off topic/opinion based flagging and to avoid XY problem.. :)

Comment: @ArunVinoth What do you mean? Please explain.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that my question was (perhaps) defined to narrowly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Encapsulation & Namespacing of jQuery](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/develop1/archive/2013/08/08/jquery-and-jquery-ui-with-dynamics-crm-2011-amp-2013) technique.

> if you would like to quickly get access to the jQuery libraries in Dynamics CRM, you can install the [SparkelXrm managed solution](https://github.com/scottdurow/SparkleXrm/blob/master/SparkleXrmSamples/SparkleXrm/SparkleXrm_0_1_0_managed.zip?raw=true) and include the web resource named ‘sparkle_/js/SparkleXrmUI_Dependancies.js’ – this is a single library that has both jQuery, jQueryUI as well as a few other goodies such as Knockout JS!

Comment: So you are essentially recommending to add jQuery as a webresource - in either a managed solution or my own - and load it in my webresource B. Is that correct?

_Sorry. I've changed the scope of my question a little, but your answer fits my question nicely no matter._

Answer (score 1):

If you can access jsquery in `webresourceA` then it means that the jquery already exists (as a webresource) in CRM. Find the url(path) of jquery and add it as a reference to the `webresourceB` and that's it.

Comment: It would work, but will fail hard and silently when CRM changes.